# Missing stylesheet.css when converting a PDF with Box View API

Tags: box-view-api

we've been testing the  Box View API and notice that for some PDFs, no stylesheet.css is returned in the .zip file, even though you can see it referenced in the SVG.

Has anyone else experienced this?  Is it due to the PDF or is it an issue with Box ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assets should always come with a stylesheet.css file for PDF conversions, so this sounds like a bug in the conversion process. If you send the files that exhibit this issue to api@box.com, someone can take a look at it and hopefully fix the problem.